# Ceiling fan malfunction

Tags: ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan keeps running at a very low speed although the power switch is turned off at the wall switch and by the pull cord. Is there any danger, and what is happening?

Comment: The only possibility, if it doesn't have electrical power, is that it's being powered by airflow. Is something else blowing on it? If not, there's more to the story than you've shared.

Comment: do you have a fancy switch, like a motion detector, glowing switch, or smart switch?

Comment: You are right, Isherwood!  I have a room air cleaner which causes slight air movement! Since I am not normally near the air cleaner I hadn't noticed the air movement. I shut off the air cleaner and the ceiling fan stopped. The air cleaner in my bedroom located closer to the ceiling fan in that room, does not cause that ceiling fan to rotate.

Comment: @isherwood or Oblio, write that in an answer so this question can have an accepted answer!

Comment: @Oblio -- write that in an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Comment: Scott sort of covered it in his opening sentence. Give it to him.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is airflow causing the fan to turn, the fan is getting power. 
Disconnect the 2 wires powering (be careful, they could be energized) the fan and do a voltage check between each wire and ground. Both should be dead. If not power is coming from somewhere.

Comment: I would use a contactless power detector instead of touching wires and hoping they're not live